# removing cyclic substrings from python list

Tags: python-2.7

I have a Python list like the following:

```
['IKW', 'IQW', 'IWK', 'IWQ', 'KIW', 'KLW', 'KWI', 'KWL', 'LKW', 'LQW', 'LWK', 'LWQ', 'QIW', 'QLW', 'QWI', 'QWL', 'WIK', 'WIQ', 'WKI', 'WKL', 'WLK', 'WLQ', 'WQI', 'WQL']
```

If we pick, say the second element `IQW`, we see that the list has duplicates of this item HOWEVER its not noticeable right away. This is because it is cyclic. I mean the following are equivalent.

`IQW`, `QWI`, `WIQ`

Also it could be backwards which is also a duplicate so I want it removed. So now the list of duplicates are (the reverse of each of one these)

`IQW`, `QWI`, `WIQ` , `WQI`, `IWQ`, `QIW`

So essentially I would like `IQW` to be the only one left. 
Bonus points, if the one that is remaining in the list is sorted alphabetically.

The way I did was to sort the entire list by alphabetical order:

```
`IQW`, `QWI`, `WIQ` , `WQI`, `IWQ`, `QIW` ->
`IQW`, `IQW`, `IQW`, `IQW`, `IQW` `IQW`
```

and then remove the duplicates. 
**However this also removes combinations say i have `ABCD` and `CDAB`. These are not the same because the ends only meet once.** But my method will sort them to `ABCD` and `ABCD` and remove one.

My code:

```
print cur_list
sortedlist = list()
for i in range(len(cur_list)):
    sortedlist.append(''.join(map(str, sorted(cur_list[i]))))
sortedlist =  set(sortedlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L = ['IKW', 'IQW', 'IWK', 'IWQ', 'KIW', 'KLW', 'KWI', 'KWL', 'LKW', 'LQW', 'LWK', 'LWQ', 'QIW', 'QLW', 'QWI', 'QWL', 'WIK', 'WIQ', 'WKI', 'WKL', 'WLK', 'WLQ', 'WQI', 'WQL']

seen = set()
res = []
for item in L:
    c = item.index(min(item))
    item = item[c:] + item[:c]
    if item not in seen:
        seen.add(item)
        seen.add(item[0]+item[-1:0:-1])
        res.append(item)

print res
```

output:

```
['IKW', 'IQW', 'KLW', 'LQW']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I coded: If anyone has a better algo, I will accept that as answer:

```
mylist = list()
for item in copy_of_cur:
    linear_peptide = item+item    
    mylist  = filter(lambda x: len(x) == 3 , subpeptides_linear(linear_peptide))
    for subitem in mylist:
        if subitem != item:
            if subitem in cur_list:
                cur_list.remove(subitem)
```